# Latitude E6440 Freezes in Windows 10 but not in Ubuntu

Tags: windows, freeze, crash

I have a bit of an unusual problem with a "new" Latitude E6440 I own. I'm trying to install Windows onto it, which succeeds, but after I setup windows and log in, it will start freezing. Sometimes it will boot all the way to the desktop and I can use it for a few minutes before freezing, other times it will crash before it even logs in. I've reinstalled windows a bunch of times and each time the install goes off without a hitch (as well as the initial setup, i.e. wifi setup, account setup, etc.), but it is quickly useless by this freezing issue.

I've swapped the SSD with another one I have, but I get the same problem. I've updated the BIOS to A24 (the latest), and reset the settings to the default, as well as setting the SATA mode to RAID, AHCI, and ATA (of course reinstalling between each). However, I've tried installing Ubuntu 20.04 and it appears to be running quite happily (at least so far, in fact I'm making this post from the laptop running in Ubuntu), which doesn't rule out a hardware issue but it definitely makes it less likely in my opinion. I've installed Windows 10 on dozens of PCs and never run into an issue like this before.

The computer has an i5 4300m CPU, and it has the Radeon 8690M, if that makes any difference. I'd try to look through the logs but it doesn't generally stay running for long enough to get to that point. The ePSA diagnostics don't come up with anything either.

I've ordered a new DDR3L RAM stick to rule that out (this computer has only one RAM stick, so I can't try pulling one), but if there's anything else I should try in the meantime I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You would need to debug the crash logs to find the issue.

Comment: If the machine freezes in Windows but not Ubuntu, that would indicate the hardware is good. Likely BIOS is also OK. So look to all your other drivers. Use the Dell Updater to update them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being a problem with the Radeon GPU driver pulled from Windows Update. It automatically gets pulled immediately after the OS installation and causes the OS to lock up once it installs. Installing the one from Dell fixes the issue (just takes some luck that the system stays running long enough for the install to happen--this can be solved in the future by leaving WiFi off when setting up Windows for the first time).

The issue is particularly devious because the lock up does not leave any logs in the Event Viewer.

Just thought I'd leave this here in case anyone else runs into the same issue.